# i want MySQL query result in same row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT sum(case when (gender)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       GROUP_CONCAT(sum(case when (gender)=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SEPARATOR ' ') as combine         
from family_member_tbl
GROUP BY gender
```

Comment: Same row? For all genders, simply remove the GROUP BY.

Comment: I don't understand the summing if genders (i.e., if gender=2, then one occurrence counts for two).  Would count work better?  If so, then @Rahul's solution can be adapted accordingly.

Comment: please provide sample of raw data and expected result, that will help a lot

Comment: i want number of male and female like this (4,5) but by above query give result like (4,0) and (0,5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you can't nest grouping function like that. Rather get the sum first and then `group_concat()` like

```
select sum_1, sum_2, group_concat(sum_2) as combine
from (
SELECT gender,
       sum(case when gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sum_1,
       sum(case when gender = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sum_2         
from family_member_tbl
GROUP BY gender ) xxx
group by gender;
```